# How can I make a cancel button halt this computation?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have three functions, handleSubmit handleCancel, and solve. HandleSubmit triggers a compute-heavy process, solve. handleCancel should stop that process early.

My simplified code looks like this:

```
import { solve } from './solve.js';
let AllowedToRun = [false];

function handleSubmit() {
  allowedToRun[0] = true;
  solve(allowedToRun);
  allowedToRun[0] = false;
}

function handleCancel() {
  allowedToRun[0] = false;
}
```

```
// solve.js
function solve(allowedToRun) {
let n = 0;
  while (n < 100000000 && allowedToRun[0]) {
    n++;
    console.log(n);
    await sleep(0); // unblock UI by chunking compute
  }
}
```

Essentially, once the user clicks submit, a compute heavy operation starts running. I chunk the compute with `await sleep(0)`, a promisified `setTimeout`, allowing for the UI to be responsive. If at any point the user clicks cancel, I mutate `allowedToRun`, which will result in the while loop in `solve` failing, canceling the computation early.

This is fine, and it works, but I would like to have this functionality without the use of mutating arrays and/or global variables. Is there a way this can be done without that? I would also like to import `solve`, so I cannot use any module-level variables in my solution.

Comment: `allowedToRun` has a different context from the `solve.js` file `solve` function and the global declaration in your main code. Passing by argument won't help, but if you export a global variable from `solve.js` then the changes made in your main code will be reflected in the file it is exported from.

Comment: I agree, passing by argument doesn't help, which is why I am currently using a reference workaround. Are you saying to declare `allowedToRun` inside `solve.js`, and export it to my main file? I had no idea that editing that variable would edit it in `solve.js`, I thought it would be a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to have this functionality without the use of mutating arrays and/or global variables

The standard solution is to use an [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal), not an array. But either way, it's an object carrying state, and you'll have to mutate it.

```
function solve(abortSignal) {
  let n = 0;
  while (n < 100000000 && !abortSignal.aborted) {
    n++;
    console.log(n);
    await sleep(0); // unblock UI by chunking compute
  }
}
```

or preferably

```
function solve(abortSignal) {
  abortSignal.throwIfAborted();
  let n = 0;
  while (n < 100000000) {
    n++;
    console.log(n);
    await sleep(0, abortSignal); // unblock UI by chunking compute
  }
}
```